# Fatal error on "git add submodule"

Tags: git

I get the following error when I try adding a submodule to my repository:

> fatal: pathspec 'submodule' did not match any files

I had some issues with my submodules so I had to remove them all (removed them from `.gitmodules`, `.git/config`, cleaned the index using `rm --cached submodule_path`, even did `git reset --mixed`).

But now I can't seem to be able to add any submodule at all! I looked through the whole .git folder in search for references to my previous submodules and couldn't find anything. Have I run out of options?

(now that I think of it I might have deleted a repository to which was referenced a submodule at some point, but that submodule is now gone so why would this be a problem?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you mean to use `git submodule add <repository> <path>`, not `git add submodule`, which would just add a file named `submodule` to your index.